# Freemarker What is the advantage of using TemplateMethodModelEx over TemplateMethodModel

Tags: freemarker

Recently we upgraded to Freemarker 2.3.22. We have implemented TemplateMethodModel interface mutliple times in our product. Now we are getting warnings that TemplateMethodModel is deprecated and consider using TemplateMethodModelEx.

Are there any specific things that can be done using TemplateMethodModelEx only?

Comment: Upgraded to 2.3.22? If you are upgrading anyway, why not upgrade to the latest stable version (`2.3.24-incubating` ATM).

Comment: The company maintains an internal artifactory and there they are upto 2.3.22 only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The advantage of `TemplateMethodModelEx` is that it accepts non-`String` method arguments. `TemplateMethodModel` has remained from the old times (1.x?) when FreeMarker only had string values.